# Drag and drop in silkTest

Tags: silktest

I tried to do a functional test that consists of drag and drop but I didn't found a way in silk4j. is there a way to do it or 
 silk4j doesn't support drag and drop tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Silk4J Browser replay and have several tests that do drag and drop.

You basically locate the object (DomElement, DomLink,..) that should be moved, invoke the pressMouse() method on it, find the target object and invoke the mouseMove() and then the releaseMouse() method on it. This should do the drag and drop.

So you just have to manually "simulate" the drag and drop.